# Difference between Apache CXF Jetty endpoint and embedded Jetty container

Tags: cxf, embedded-jetty

I started building a web application and made it runnable with an embedded Jetty server. I then decided to try out Apache CXF (which I have never used before) to provide either a SOAP/XML or a REST/JSON interface (haven't decided which yet). Now I am slightly confused by the various posts / docs I have read.

I understand that CXF actually provides (using Jetty internally) its own endpoints that can be published. Is that correct? But it looks like it can also be bundled and deployed into existing web containers (eg Tomcat, and therefore I assume also Jetty) - is this also correct?

If both of these are correct, what are the pros / cons / gotchas of using the CXF Jetty endpoints out-of-the-box as opposed to using a separate container (especially if the separate container is also embedded Jetty)?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your application and deployment strategy. Jetty is a lightweight, embedded application server that you can use to run your own web-server. If you choose Apache Tomcat or JBoss or any other application server your application will be likely packaged as a WAR and deployed. The difference is , in Jetty your application controls the container whereas with others its the other way around. Regardless of the choice of application server , CXF endpoints are designed to work with any container supporting JAX-RS or JAX-WS specifications.

Note: You don't need Jetty if you are going to deploy it on Tomcat or other containers.

Comment: But what is the difference (if any) between the CXF Jetty (<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId><artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>) and adding Jetty separately (<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId><artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>) ?

Comment: from [CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/using-cxf-with-maven.html) ,  cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty is needed if you are using Jetty as embedded container for publishing your endpoints. It provides the plumming required for CXF to work with Jetty. I am not sure what `jetty-webapp` does but I believe it is a helper JAR shipped with standard Jetty distribution